# Add category filter

Tags: php, magento, filter, categories

I want to add category filter in **sales_order_create** grid of product listing in magento, 
I have successfully add category dropdown in filter but when I hit search for using this category filter I am redirecting to main dashboard page, so what is the issue I don't understand my other custom filter work properly on this page but this category filter is not working.
I have passed category_ids as name and index.
I have found this error
**Invalid attribute name: category_ids.**

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that there is no column "category_ids" in the fetched tables. You should override the grid (if you haven't done yet) and make a `join`, or add a `->where()`-statement to the collection for each category id chosen.